# Print line in file until line blank line

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, text, blank-line

I have a file "testread.txt" having below data.

```
A
1
2
3
4

BA
5
6
7
8

CB
9
10
11

D
12
13
14
15
```

I Wanted to read and extract data each section wise and write it to different files. Eg;

```
1
2
3
4
```

Write it to File "a.txt"

```
5
6
7
8
```

Write it to File "b.txt"

```
9
10
11
```

Write it to File "c.txt"
and so on...

Comment: please provide [mcve] of your attempt

Comment: @depperm MCVEs are only required for code which requires debugging, which can't be assumed as OP hasn't stated any problems or shown any attempts. There is nothing to verify and reproduce.

Comment: Split by newline and write it

Comment: @TrebledJ I'm trying to let OP know to attempt the problem before asking SO to do it for them

Comment: @depperm Sure, but linking the MCVE help page is a bold guess that the OP has existing code. For all we know, maybe no code has been written at all and may confuse OP. [ask] or [It appears no attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/#introduction) may be more suitable.

Answer (score 1):

A (rough) solution could be get using:

1. [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to divide and store items;
2. [`numpy.savetxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) to save them into files.

```
import numpy as np
from collections import defaultdict

with open('testread.txt', 'r') as f:
    content = f.readlines()

d = defaultdict(list)

i = 0
for line in content:
    if line == '\n':
        i+=1
    else:
        d[i].append(line.strip())

for k,v in d.items():
    np.savetxt('file{}.txt'.format(k), v[1:], delimiter=",", fmt='%s')
```

and you get:

- `file0.txt`

```
1
2
3
4
```

- `file1.txt`:

```
5
6
7
8
```

- `file2.txt`:

```
9
10
11
```

- file3.txt

```
12
13
14
15
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to skip file when a new empty line is available. The below code should do the trick.

```
files_list = ['a.txt', 'b.txt', 'c.txt']
fpr = open('input.txt')
for f in files_list:
    with open(f, 'w') as fpw:
        for i, line in enumerate(fpr):
            if i == 0:   # skips first line
                continue
            if line.strip():
                fpw.write(line)
            else:
                break
```

Comment: Thank You Praveen.... I also wanted to remove title of first line A,BA,CB, and include unique values from each section.

Comment: Hi @AmitTiwari, I have edited the code to skip first line. This should work.